# Is true the boundary of compact set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ have Measure Zero?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ open and $f:\Omega \rightarrow [0, \infty[$ a measurable function. Suppose that there exist $C>0$ such that $$\int_K f dm < C,\ \forall\ K\subset\Omega,\ K\ \mbox{compact}.$$  Let $(K_j)$ be a sequence of subsets of $\Omega$ satisfying: $$K_j \subset \operatorname{int} (K_{j+1}), \ \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} K_j = \Omega   .$$ I need to prove that

$$\lim_{j \rightarrow \infty} \int_{K_j} f dm = \sup \{ \int_K f dm: K \subset \Omega, K \mbox{compact} \} . $$

If we can prove that $m(\partial K)=0$, we can use that $\int_K f dm = \int_{\operatorname{int}(K)} f dm $ and find a sequence $(\int_{\operatorname{int}(K_j)} f dm)$ with $$\int_{\operatorname{int}(K_j)} f dm \rightarrow \sup\{ \int_{\operatorname{int}(K_j)} f dm : j \in \mathbb{N}\}.$$  Now we note that that $\{ \int_K f dm: K \subset \Omega, K \ \mbox{compact} \} \subset   \{ \int_K f dm: K \subset \Omega, K\ \mbox{compact} \}$, and we can find an inequality. For another I thought to write $K = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} K_{j}   $ and try to play with their interior.

Do you think that I'm in the right away? And the question about boundary is true?

Comment: There are [Cantor sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) with positive measure, and all Cantor sets are equal to their boundaries and compact.

Comment: Also, the boundary of Mandelbrot set is of dimension $2$.

Comment: @Golbez: Dimension and measure are not the same.

Answer (score 3):

As commenters explained, the boundary of a compact set can have positive measure. How to proceed with the proof of
$$\lim_{j \rightarrow \infty} \int_{K_j} f\, dm = \sup \left\{ \int_K\, f dm: K \subset \Omega, \ K \mbox{compact} \right\} $$
then?

The inequality $\le$ holds because every $K_j$ is also eligible for the supremum on the right.

To prove $\ge$, it suffices to show that for every compact $K$ there is $j$ such that $K\subset K_j$. Hint: since $\bigcup_j \operatorname{int}K_j=\Omega $, you have an open cover of $K$.

Comment: Would it not be easier to use monotone convergence to conclude $\lim_j \int_{K_j} f \, dm = \int_\Omega f \, dm$, which makes $\geq$ trivial? This also shows that the assumption about the interiors is superfluous.

Comment: @PhoemueX Makes sense. On the other hand, the approach in my answer applies to every monotone set function (such as capacity), not just $\int_K f\,dm$. This is probably why I thought of it.

Comment: You guys are right, I did it.Thank you!

Comment: For the $\leq$ part, how is $K_j$ eligible on the right. It's not compact, just a subset.